# Size of data on WebRTC Data Channel between native app and browser

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I have a data channel between my native webrtc application and a firefox browser. When I send a 200Kb image data from the native app to the firefox browser I get the following error:

```
(sctpdataengine.cc:672): ERROR:SctpDataMediaChannel->SendData(...):  usrsctp_sendv:  : [0x0000005a] Message too long
(datachannel.cc:580): Closing the DataChannel due to a failure to send data, send_result = 1
```

I have read about [limitations between browsers](https://gist.github.com/lgrahl/763a4ba303f900188f8042c5aa810cd9) and was wondering if the same limitations apply to native apps too. If anybody has any idea about this please let me know.

Thanks